# Animation with parts at different starting time

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

Working with animations, I am facing a simple question.

For now I use this kind of code and it all works fine. For clarity I do not put here the inside of the blocks, for it would be irrelevant to the question.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

The animation starts and ends as expected. Here comes my question:
From now on I want part(s) of the animation to start with a delay, for example animationDuration/2;
and I want everything to finish as before, that means the part(s) of the animation starting with the delay should now run faster in order to end at the same time as the rest.

What is the best (and standard) way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration-delayInt
                  delay:delayInt
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
             animations:^{}
             completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I still want to keep the biggest chunk of the animation working like before. So should I have 2 [[UIView animateWithDuration:...] launched together? I mean the one I already use and the one you propose.

Comment: you can do this, if the animation is a single chunk or you can keep a nested animation but that would require u to make a calculation for delay as well and not account for the faster animation coz for that you will have to lower the animation duration

Comment: I need to experiment, I just tried to do what you suggested from inside the animations:^{} block, but it does not seem to produce something perfectly synchronized. The ending is OK though.

Comment: play around with the code with the timings, you will get your desired effect with nested animation blocks

Comment: You mean "nesting animation blocks" is the way to go?
Not having two [UIView animateWithDuration:...] launched one beside the other?